# Field of required type Int! was not provided.",

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, orm, graphql

I have the following GraphQL error:
message": "Field JobInput.salarys of required type Int! was not provided.",

I have declared three variables of mutation and i´m not sure of the " salarys: number;" right?

Answer (score 0):

`JobInput` requires `salarys` field, you have provided `salary` in the screenshot

```
class JobInput {
    @Field()
    title: string

    @Field(() => Int)
    salarys: number;
}
```

Changing your mutation input to

```
options: {
 title: 'my title',
 salarys: 8000
}
```

should work. It's a typo, I guess.

Comment: unfortunately the same Error

Comment: Is that right ```   @Field(() => Int)
    @Column("int", { default: 10 })
    salarys: number; ```